# Ubuntu Command Line to force running application from secondary (or specific) monitor

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, vlc, multiple-monitors

I'm creating an application (command line script) to play videos directly to the secondary monitor, which is connected either via VGA or HDMI.

The video player itself is cvlc, with command cvlc -f myvideo.avi.

Can anyone please help about the script to run the cvlc directly to secondary monitor regardless of which monitor it was launched from.

i've tried DISPLAY=":0.1" vlc -f myvideo.avi, but results a scrambled unusable video player.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `--x11-display :0.1` flag. It's not part of the `--help` output but I use it on my 2.0.1 vlc.

Comment: Other clue is, i found out that my pc doesn't have :0.1 display, but instead, there's only one :0.0 display. But i can confirm that, there are 2 monitors with different display/windows, say monitor 1 displaying firefox and other is showing terminal.

Comment: @Lee well, if there's no display :0.1, obviously this isn't going to work. Maybe there's some way to place the window at a certain coordinate if your monitors are one contiguous display.

Comment: monitor one is at 1366x768, and monitor 2 is 1440x900, xrandr says screen 0 is at 2806x900 resolution. any clue on this? thanks before.

Comment: @Lee, I don't know how to make vlc open the display at a certain coordinate, but that's where you probably want to look (if it's even possible). My guess is that if you want it to display at monitor 2, you want to start your X coordinate at 1367.

Comment: thanks. i also found that VLC is remembering the last position (monitor) where it was shown. Any idea, where does VLC store this information? so i write position.